# Sufficient statistics for a non exponential

Tags: mathematical-statistics, sufficient-statistics, exponential-family

I think this is not an exponential family but does it mean that we can't find a sufficient statistic for $\theta$ if $X_1, X_2,..., X_n$ are a random sample from this density?
$$ f_{\theta} (x) = \frac{6x(\theta - x)}{\theta^3} $$$$ 0<x<\theta$$

Comment: If random variable $X$ has density $f(x) = 6x(1-x),$ for $0 < x < 1,$ then $X\sim\mathsf{Beta}(2,2).$ So your question is about a sample from a beta distribution modified ('generalized") to have support $(0, \theta).$ See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution) on beta distributions or your text.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few exceptions to the rule that only exponential families have sufficient statistics of fixed dimension (not depending on sample size $n$), like the uniform distribution family. In that case the parameter is the upper interval limit, and that is the case for your density also.

So it is better to look carefully at your case! I will only give a hint:  Use the [factorization theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sufficient_statistic#Fisher%E2%80%93Neyman_factorization_theorem).